# Can't select text in Google Chrome neither in FF but it works in IE 10

Tags: css, html, select, absolute

I'm currently developing a website but I'm facing a little problem.

The problem is that on Google Chrome, Firefox and Safari, I can't select text neither click on links in the middle part of the page.

But in IE 10 it is working I can select text or click on links.

Sources are available by doing a right click then "View page source" :)

Do somebody know why do I have this strange behaviour? I think that it is because the top div is overlapping the middle div but I don't know how to fix it :(

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Proof of the web developer's mantra: "If it works in IE, but not the other browsers, you're markup is wrong."

Answer (score 1):

You need to move all the div `#middle` and all its contents inside the div `#wrapper` between the footer and the header like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <header></header>
   <div id="middle"></div>
   <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Then you need to add `z-index:999;` css to the div `#top`.

Comment: It is indeed solving my issue. But after this modification, the content of the middle, if too long, is overlapping over the top and bottom part of the site. Is it a way to keep the top and bottom part which contains the menus over the middle part if this one is too long.

Comment: Great it is perfectly working! Thanks a lot!
I did forgot about the z-index trick :)